# awk - awk concatenate string variable

Tags: awk, string

I would like to awk concatenate string variable in awk. How can I do that?
I tried:

```
BEGIN{
t="."
r=";"
w=t+r
print w}
```

But I does't work.
Output:

```
0
```

Or I want to add variable and result of function.
Input:

```
t t t t
a t a ta
ata ta a a
```

Script:

```
{
key="t"
print gsub(key,"")#<-it's work
b=b+gsub(key,"")#<- it's something wrong
}
END{
print b}#<-so this is 0
```

Output:

```
4
2
2
0#<-the last print
```

Comment: With `t+r` you implicitly cast both variables to numbers, and both become zero. Strings resembling numbers are converted to numbers: `t="1";r="2";w=t+r;print w` prints `3`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No operator is needed (or used).  Your example would be something like

```
BEGIN{
t="."
r=";"
w=t r
print w}
```

For related discussion

- [6.2.2 String Concatenation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html) in The GNU Awk Manual
- [string concatenation in AWK](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/string-concatenation-in-awk-19033/) on Linux Questions
- [Concatenate strings in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912175/concatenate-strings-in-awk) on StackOverflow

Comment: Ok. I have one more problem. I would like to make arithmetic operation:
b=b+gsub(key,""). I will add this in my post.

Comment: @diego9403: post it as a new question instead

Comment: agree - the addition to OP's question exercises a different aspect of strings.